# C++ and Windows - how to overwrite exe file of the running program?

Tags: c++, windows, locking

I tried to make self-updatable program, but I can't understand, how to over-write exe file of the running program (of the current process). When Exe file is running, it's locked by process and can't be writable.

How to update program - I need to update file, close current process and re-run updated file...

Maybe my question is silly, but I haven't this problem, until I used Linux... 
Cheers! ❤

Comment: Start another process (different file), overwrite the exe, start again?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it... But, I think, it isn't good solution - it's adds another one file...

Comment: Launch a [self-deleting executable](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables). If you are worried about distributing another file, you can always wrap it up as a binary resource, and extract it on demand.

Comment: Hi. I can't understand phrase " as a binary resource, and extract it on demand". Can you provide some tutorial about this? Thank you!

Comment: You could perform some research and web searches. This is too broad a question for SO, though, as it is essentially "how do I make an installer" rather than a specific question about a specific piece of programming code.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it now... But I can't imagine, how to add resource, that is not bitmap files into the my exe file, in the Visual Studio...

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiceeeeeeeeeeee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question by packing needed file into the another one wrapper via Resources in MS VS.

Here is code to extract resource into the file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "windows.h"


int main()
{
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_BINARYTYPE1), _T("BINARYTYPE"));
        //FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_BINARYTYPE1), RT_BITMAP);
    HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    LPVOID lpLock = LockResource(hLoaded);
    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("c:/temp/zxcv.exe"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD dwByteWritten;
    WriteFile(hFile, lpLock, dwSize, &dwByteWritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    FreeResource(hLoaded);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not realized it by 100%, but I have plan to pack my exe into the wrapper, that will unpack my exe into the %Temp% directory and will start unpacked exe file. Unpacked file will be deleted with DELETE_ON_CLOSE.

It's just plan, but I see possible solution :).

Thanks to all!

Comment: If you down vote my answer, please, leave comment, why you down vote.

Thank you! ❤